# What is the probability of interpolating the Tutte polynomial of a planar graph from the values at the two hyperbolas?

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials, integer-programming, interpolation

The [Tutte polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial)
is a bivariate polynomial with positive integer coefficient which is a graph
invariant and can be defined recursively.

Evaluating it is $\#P$-complete even when restricted to (bipartite or maximum
degree 3) planar graphs.

[A paper p. 12](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Edeloera/MISC/BIBLIOTECA/trunk/Welsh/welsh-tutte-polynomial.pdf) gives some special (algebraic) points
where it can be polynomially computable.

[Another paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1114122) shows
for planar graphs it can be polynomially computed at special points and
the two hyperbolas $H_1(x,y)=0,H_2(x,y)=0, H_q(x,y)=(x-1)(y-1)-q$.

Univariate polynomial of degree $d$ can be found from $d+1$
pairs $(x_i,f(x_i))$, but the bivariate case is more complicated.

Assume the graph $G$ is planar and possibly bipartite
or maximum degree $3$. Let the Tutte polynomial be $T_G(x,y)$.

Having in mind the positivity constraint, I tried
to find $T_G(x,y)$ from $(x_i,y_i,T_G(x_i,y_i))$
where $(x_i,y_i)$ are the few special points and
points on $H_1,H_2$.

Chose the degree $d$, for unknowns $c_{i,j}$ write
$F_G(x,y)=\sum_{i,j} c_{i,j}x^iy^j$ and equate $F_G(x_i,y_i)=T_G(x_i,y_i)$.
Add the constraints $c_{i,j} \ge 0$ and for the algebraic
special points work over a number field, equating the algebraic
integers. Make the equations integral by scaling.

We get an integer program $L$ which has at least one solution
$T_G(x,y)$.

If the solution is unique (it need not be) we have found the Tutte
polynomial with one call to $NP$-complete oracle,
which appears nontrivial result to me.

The non-negativity constraint appears very important,
since over $\mathbb{Z}$ the matrix is low rank
because of the structure from the hyperbolas
(I suspect if $(x_i,y_i)$ were random it would
have worked even over $\mathbb{Z}$).

> Q1 What is the probability $L$ has unique solution?
>
> Q2 Does some constraint on the planar graph guarantee
> unique solution?

---

Experimental results which might be misleading
and assuming the integrity of the `isl` solver.

Graphs are connected planar, non-trees.
A graph is bad if the solution is not unique.

On $8$ vertices:  bipartite $135$, bad $8$

On $8$ vertices:  maximum degree $3$ all $177$ bad $3$

On $9$ vertices:  bipartite $535$ bad $100$

On $9$ vertices:  maximum degree $3$ all $496$ bad $46$

---

---

Some remarks. $H_2$ is $\#P$ hard on general graphs and
is closely related to counting CUTS.

On $H_1$ there is very simple closed form for $T_G$.

On $H_2$ there is no simple closed form for $T_G$.

A paper defines thickening of $G$ which is multigraph $G'$
with each edge of $G$ replaced by $k$ parallel edges.

$T_G$ and $T_G'$ are related:  $T_G'(x,y)=T_G(f(x,y),g(x,y))$
and this gives more interpolation points.

Unless I am mistaken, this doesn't help for more interpolation
points, since $H_2$ stays the same.

Comment: The values of polynomials $f(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)+p(x,y)H_1(x,y)H_2(x,y)$ do not differ on these hyperbolas, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yes, this is trivially true. All solutions are equal modulo $H_1,H_2$.